# getting error while connecting to redshift from aws lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

trying to connecting redshift from aws lambda python code using psycopg2 lib, when running same code from EC2 instance not getting any error. getting below error response.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"::xxxxx\", user \"xxxx\", database \"xxxx\", SSL off\n",
  "errorType": "OperationalError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/aws_unload_to_s3_audit.py",
      86,
      "lambda_handler",
      "mainly()"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/aws_unload_to_s3_audit.py",
      74,
      "mainly",
      "con = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)"
    ],
    [
      "/var/task/psycopg2/__init__.py",
      130,
      "connect",
      "conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Issue got resolved, previously using psycopg2 library without ssl support. tried with psycopg2 with ssl support now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion on this would be putting checking the network configuration for Redshift, chances are that the connection is being refused.

Places to check -

1. Redshift Security Group
2. VPC configuration is the lambda resides under a private subnet.